# How to send an Email if a condition fails using Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a python script that calculates delays and data received everyday. My data frame looks like this:

```
Country Date Delay Data_Rec
BE       XX   0/1  0-100
CA       XX   0/1  0-100
DE       XX   0/1  0-100
NL       XX   0/1  0-100
```

The delay can be either 0 or 1 depending on the data received and the data received can be anything between 0-100. If the data received is 100 then delay is 0 else delay is 1 and perc_rec could be anything <100. What I'm trying to solve is just send an email to abcd@xyz.com if my delay>0 & data_rec<100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the standard library, with the smtp module : 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

If you scroll to the end there is an example, you just have to know your smtp details, like the ones you are giving when you configure a email client.

To know if the data is exceeding a threshold, you can use binary masks :

```
mask = (df['delay'] > 0) & (df['data_rec'] < 100)
if mask:
    # send mail
```

(non tested code, but i think it is close to okay)